# How to upload an image to Google Firestore Bucket

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-storage

Currently I am trying to allow users to upload profile pictures to a firestore bucket through my python API. I am trying to send the image in the form data of a request. However, when I try to upload the image, I get the following error,
"TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"
Here it is:

```
@users_endpoints.route('/addProfilePicture', methods=['POST'])
def add_profile_picture():
    request_data = request.form['some_text']
    print(request_data)
    imagefile = request.files.get('imagefile', False)
    # imagefile.save('/Users/joeytrasatti/Moove/test.jpg')

    # auth_token = body.get('token')
    # if not auth_token:
    #     return no_auth_token_response()
    # uid, utype = auth.decode_auth_token(auth_token)
    image_blob = bucket.blob(f'users/test')
    image_blob.upload_from_filename(imagefile.stream.read())

    return make_response(jsonify(True)), 200
```

I am able to save the file to my computer, and I can upload saved files, I just cant upload the file from the request directly. I have tried to decode the request using:

```
image_blob.upload_from_filename(imagefile.stream.read().decode('utf-8')
```

but I then got the following error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I was able to get it closer to what I want by using this line instead of the previous upload line!

```
image_blob.upload_from_file(imagefile.stream)
```

However, it is stored as a application/octet-stream file. Is there anyway that I can store it as a jpeg?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `content_type` option to [`google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/v1.35.0/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L2197).

imagefile which is an instance of [`werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/1.0.1/src/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L2960) has a `content_type` attribute that you can get this value from.

```py
image_blob.upload_from_file(
    imagefile.stream,
    content_type=imagefile.content_type
)
```